# Elm quicksort visualization

Tags: haskell, quicksort, elm

I'm trying to display the sorting process of quicksort with Elm

```
[ 5, 8, 6, 2, 4, 1, 0, 3, 10, 7, 9 ]
[2,4,1,0,3]      5      [8,6,10,7,9]
[1,0] 2 [4,3]         [6,7] 8 [10,9]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
```

Right now i can get the first 2 lines but I'm unsure how to approach this in a recursive manner.

```
list_to_html : List (List Int) -> Html msg
list_to_html x =
    div [] [ x |> toString |> text ]

quicksort_partition : List Int -> Html msg
quicksort_partition list =
    case list of
        x :: xs ->
            let
                lower =
                    List.filter ((>=) x) xs

                higher =
                    List.filter ((<) x) xs
            in
            list_to_html [ lower, [ x ], higher ]

        [] ->
            list_to_html []
```

This outputs:

```
[ 5, 8, 6, 2, 4, 1, 0, 3, 10, 7, 9 ]
[2,4,1,0,3]     [5]     [8,6,10,7,9]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to get that kind of output, direct recursion inside the view isn't going to work well. Instead, I would approach it as writing a variation of quicksort which logs the state along the way.

Here is an example of quicksort which also returns a list of logs. The type aliases are included to try and make the function annotation more clear:

```elm
type alias Depth =
    Int


type alias Log comparable =
    ( Depth, List comparable, comparable, List comparable )


quicksortLog : Depth -> List comparable -> ( List comparable, List (Log comparable) )
quicksortLog depth list =
    case list of
        [] ->
            ( [], [] )

        x :: xs ->
            let
                ( lower, lowerLog ) =
                    quicksortLog (depth + 1) (List.filter ((>=) x) xs)

                ( higher, higherLog ) =
                    quicksortLog (depth + 1) (List.filter ((<) x) xs)

                log =
                    ( depth, lower, x, higher )
            in
                ( lower ++ [ x ] ++ higher, log :: lowerLog ++ higherLog )
```

Given that result, you could then write a view which displays the data in the way you see fit.